# LaunchImage not running my custom images

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode6, launchimage

I have no idea why my LaunchImage is not running. here are two images that clearly shows that i have done the right thing ( i hope :P )

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I run in this issue too. In order to get my launch images working, I had to let the field `Launch Screen File` empty.

Once that done, your LaunchImages should run.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As posted above, you have to decide whether you want to use LaunchImages or the LaunchScreen. The LaunchScreen is an .xib file where you can build the LaunchImage programmatically. If you use it then it will overwrite the LaunchImages, make sure to use just one of them and leave the `LaunchScreen File` field empty.

Hope that helps you :)